# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'proceed' of undefined

Tags: javascript, highcharts, gitlab

I'm trying to draw some charts using Highcharts Javascript charting engine, I have it all set up, it works fine in my local development environment, but when I deploy it to Gitlab and access it, it is giving me the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'proceed' of undefined
    at t.<computed> (main-es2015.7538dcc357c548058d75.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main-es2015.7538dcc357c548058d75.js:1)
    at Object.t.<computed> [as arc] (main-es2015.7538dcc357c548058d75.js:1)
    at A.getPlotBandPath (main-es2015.7538dcc357c548058d75.js:1)
    at s.renderBackground (main-es2015.7538dcc357c548058d75.js:1)
    at s.render (main-es2015.7538dcc357c548058d75.js:1)
    at main-es2015.7538dcc357c548058d75.js:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at t.each (main-es2015.7538dcc357c548058d75.js:1)
    at t.Chart.<anonymous> (main-es2015.7538dcc357c548058d75.js:1)
```

I am trying to get my Gitlab commits from my public projects in order to analyze the number of commits from a specific language or library and place them in a chart so that the user can see the difference.

I have googled this error and I have found very similar ones, but none of them has been the solution to my problem. I also tried looking for the property `proceed` in my platform, but it looks like it is something that highcharts is running or calling when executing.

I'm using this to build the component:

```
if (this.data.gitlab) {
      this.seriesData.push({
        name: 'GitLab',
        y: this.data.gitlab,
        color: '#e24329',
        radius: `${radius}%`,
        innerRadius: `${radius - 7}%`
      });
      this.seriesBackgrounds.push({
        outerRadius: `${radius}%`,
        innerRadius: `${radius - 7}%`,
        borderWidth: 0
      });
    }
```

And this to create the chart:

```
this.skillChart = new Chart(<any>{
      chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge',
        spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0],
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderColor: 'transparent'
      },
      title: null,
      pane: {
        center: ['50%', '80%'],
        size: '130%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: this.seriesBackgrounds
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: this.maxScore,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
        minorTickWidth: 0,
        tickWidth: 0,
        labels: {
          enabled: false
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        followPointer: true,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {point.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
      },
      series: [
        {
          animation: {
            duration: 1500
          },
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
          },
          data: this.seriesData
        }
      ]
    });
```

When I run the platform I expect to see a chart showing a semi-circular bar with the number of commits with 10 as the top, which is just what I get when I run the platform in my local environment.

But instead, when I run from the deployed Gitlab platform, I get the component but the chart does not draw the semicircle.

I have not enough reputation to post the images, otherwise, it would have been easier for people to see what I mean.

Comment: What's your build process? That stacktrace is coming from something minified.

Comment: I am using Gitlab CI as a build process

Comment: Unfortunately, that tells us nothing. What configuration? What plugins/steps? Again, that stack trace is coming from minified code, I'm assuming you don't write hundreds if not thousands of characters on a single line by hand.

Comment: Could you try to reproduce this issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle? Try to simplify it and use the sample data structure from your production code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've fallen in the very same issue. My observation: I'm using Highcharts JS v6.1.4 (2018-09-25) installed with NPM via angular-highcharts.

When debugging the code is breaking in the minified code related to this fragment of highcharts.src.js:

```
/**
 * Wrap a method with extended functionality, preserving the original function.
 *
 * @function Highcharts.wrap
 *
 * @param {*} obj
 *        The context object that the method belongs to. In real cases, this is
 *        often a prototype.
 *
 * @param {string} method
 *        The name of the method to extend.
 *
 * @param {Function} func
 *        A wrapper function callback. This function is called with the same
 *        arguments as the original function, except that the original function
 *        is unshifted and passed as the first argument.
 */
H.wrap = function (obj, method, func) {
    var proceed = obj[method];
    obj[method] = function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        outerArgs = arguments,
        ctx = this,
        ret;
        ctx.proceed = function () {
            proceed.apply(ctx, arguments.length ? arguments : outerArgs);
        };
        args.unshift(proceed);
        ret = func.apply(this, args);
        ctx.proceed = null;
        return ret;
    };
};
```

The minified code, formated, is like this:

```
a.wrap = function(a, h, e) {
    var m = a[h];
    a[h] = function() {
        var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
            , p = arguments
            , u = this;
        u.proceed = function() {
            m.apply(u, arguments.length ? arguments : p)
        }
        ;
        a.unshift(m);
        a = e.apply(this, a);
        u.proceed = null;
        return a
    }
}
;
```

I've deployed in 2 environments; in one of them, the code works, but it does not in the other. In the failing one, I debugged and `this` variable is unassigned when reaching the assignment: `u = this` therefore an error is raised in the next line: `u.proceed = function() {`.

In my other environment, `this` has `Window` as value, which has a `proceed` attribute, and then everything works fine.

I have not figured out why this is happening so far.

I hope this can help somehow.

**Edit:** Upgrading `angular-highcharts` to `8.0.3` version and `highcharts` to `7.2.0` version fixed the issue for me :)