# Highcharts Plugin Recently Broke - "this.init is not a function"

Tags: highcharts

I have a js file that create a Highcharts chart object.  I added a plugin to change label contrast.  The plugin is below:

```
/**
* Override getContrast function; make threshold for showing white text very high
*/
(function(H) {
    H.Renderer.prototype.getContrast = function(rgba) {
      rgba = H.Color(rgba).rgba;
      return rgba[0] + rgba[1] + rgba[2] > 210 ? '#000000' : '#FFFFFF';
    };
}(Highcharts));
```

It was working just fine for several months.  I recently noticed that the chart is no longer rendering, and my error console is showing this: Uncaught TypeError: this.init is not a function
    at Object.e [as Color] (highcharts.src.js:2839)

I was able to trace the source back to this part of the Highcharts.src.js file:

```
        /**
         * Handle color operations. Some object methods are chainable.
         *
         * @param {Highcharts.ColorType} input
         *        The input color in either rbga or hex format
         */
        function Color(input) {
            // Collection of parsers. This can be extended from the outside by pushing
            // parsers to Highcharts.Color.prototype.parsers.
            this.parsers = [{
                    // RGBA color
                    // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
                    regex: /rgba\(\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]?(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\s*\)/,
                    parse: function (result) {
                        return [
                            pInt(result[1]),
                            pInt(result[2]),
                            pInt(result[3]),
                            parseFloat(result[4], 10)
                        ];
                    }
                }, {
                    // RGB color
                    regex: /rgb\(\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*\)/,
                    parse: function (result) {
                        return [pInt(result[1]), pInt(result[2]), pInt(result[3]), 1];
                    }
                }];
            this.rgba = [];
            this.init(input);  //<!--ERROR RIGHT HERE
        }
```

It looks like something change internally on Highcharts' end, specifically the init() method for the Color subclass.  Has anyone else had a similar error?

Comment: I've seen highcharts doing some [weird things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57960871/error-typeerror-cannot-set-property-proceed-of-undefined/58615766#58615766). Please try upgrading the library if you didn't yet.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue on some online editor which I could debug? Or you can report this issue directly on Highcharts Github issue channel where core developers will respond you. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v8.0.1, Highcharts.Color must be instanciated with the new keyword.

Before

```
            stops: [
                [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
            ]
```

Since v8.0.1

```
            stops: [
                [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                [1, new Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
            ]
```

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13053

Comment: Thanks!  I will try this and mark your answer as correct if it works.  In the meantime, I have upvoted it.